# How to deserialize a like List<MyObject> with GSON

Tags: android, gson

Hi i serialized a list `List<Show> list;` to pass it through an intent using

```
String listSerializedToJson = new Gson().toJson(mShowAdapter.getList());
```

Now In the other activity I got the json like this:

```
String listSerializedToJson = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LIST_OF_OBJECTS");
```

How do I transform it back into a `List<Show> list;`?

Comment: Questions are similar but the answer here is more concise and pertinent, so I'm leaving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Show>>(){}.getType();
List<Show> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(listSerializedToJson , listType);
```